# LinearLayout Fill Percent Of Background

Tags: java, android, background, android-linearlayout, percentage

I am trying to fill a certain percent of a (horizontal) item's background.

I have tried this as many people have recommended:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fill_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:background="#000"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

But the problem is that I have many more layout's below that and this layout end's up pushing the rest to the right like so:
[image]

How do I make this new LinearLayout background layout go behind the rest of the layouts? Here is my full xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="@color/optionItemBackgroundColor"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fill_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:background="@color/percent_fill_color"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/percentText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/optionItemTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/option_text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/votesText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/optionItemTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/num_votes_text_size"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:textColor="@color/optionItemTextColor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/option_text_size" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please reframe your question as it is not clear what you are trying to do/ask. Also link to other SO questions that you said have tried. That will help get context.

Comment: you want to set color to your Linearlayout background ???

Comment: I would like to fill a percent of my linear layout's background to a color. The percent should be able to be changed programictially.

Comment: for EX, you have 2 linear layout 1 with 80% and 2 is with 20% ??

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to achieve like this try this code  [image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#e11f1f"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fill_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:background="#000"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

if your trying to to get this view try this [image: image2]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fill_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:background="#000"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Kind of. When I have added the inner linear layout it ends up moving the rest of my layout's already in the linearlayout.

Comment: can you post a screen shot of what you are getting

Comment: Which one you want to get the first view or second view

Comment: Second. Btw it's a list item.

Comment: can you be more specific it would be helpful if you upload a screen shot of what you are getting and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I added a picture to the question

Comment: I made the question much more clear. Do you get it now?

Comment: @Jared You are not using the layout weight property properly. Give your full xml code I will try to help you with your issue

Comment: I added my full xml but I don't think that'll make a difference from what you already knew.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/optionItemBackgroundColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fill_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:background="@color/percent_fill_color"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: for EX, you have 2 linear layout 1 with 80% and 2 is with 20% ??